# PHP Explode - Multiple Lines With Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am using the following code to change my array of data (comma seperated but not from a file) to an array that can be used. My code is as follows...

```
public function exportPartsAuthority($fileArray)
{       
    // Do whatever - sample code for a webservice request below.
    foreach ($fileArray as $filename => $fileContent) {

        // Do nothing

    }

    foreach(explode("\n",$fileContent) as $line){
        $item=explode(",",$line);
        file_put_contents('/home/apndev/public_html/output.txt', print_r($item, true));
    }

}
```

The values of $fileContent are seen below...

```
"100000002","flatrate_flatrate","1.0000","Brian","","","","","Sunrise","33323","Florida","US","","",
"100000002","flatrate_flatrate","1.0000","Brian","","","","","Sunrise","33323","Florida","US","","",
"100000003","flatrate_flatrate","1.0000","Brian","","","","","Sunrise","33323","Florida","US","2P-225","A1",
```

And this is how it's coming out in my file after exploding $fileContent...

```
Array
(
[0] => "100000002"
[1] => "flatrate_flatrate"
[2] => "1.0000"
[3] => "Brian"
[4] => ""
[5] => ""
[6] => ""
[7] => ""
[8] => "Sunrise"
[9] => "33323"
[10] => "Florida"
[11] => "US"
[12] => ""
[13] => ""
[14] => 
"100000002"
[15] => "flatrate_flatrate"
[16] => "1.0000"
[17] => "Brian"
[18] => ""
[19] => ""
[20] => ""
[21] => ""
[22] => "Sunrise"
[23] => "33323"
[24] => "Florida"
[25] => "US"
[26] => ""
[27] => ""
[28] => 
"100000003"
[29] => "flatrate_flatrate"
[30] => "1.0000"
[31] => "Brian"
[32] => ""
[33] => ""
[34] => ""
[35] => ""
[36] => "Sunrise"
[37] => "33323"
[38] => "Florida"
[39] => "US"
[40] => "2P-225"
[41] => "A1"
[42] => 
)
```

How would I go about producing each line from that string as its own array?

Comment: your input data is flawed already, fix that first

Comment: I've hidden a lot of data because it's personal information. How is it flawed otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually really close, as you're already creating a new array for each line with your call to `explode()` -- you just need a variable to hold all the `$item`s you're creating, and add `$item` in each iteration through your loop:

```
function exportPartsAuthority($fileArray) {       

    //this would hold your output
    $arrayOfArrays = array();

    foreach ($fileArray as $filename => $fileContent) {

        // Do nothing
        foreach(explode("\n",$fileContent) as $line){
            $item=explode(",",$line);
            file_put_contents('/home/apndev/public_html/output.txt', print_r($item, true));

            //now add it to your arrayOfArrays
            $arrayOfArrays[] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```